# Cannot access SQL Server Express on Mac using Docker

Tags: docker, sql-server-express, parallels

I use Visual Studio 2022 on Windows Parallels on a MacBook Pro M2 chip. My goal is to use SQL Server Express on Windows Parallels. I found this guide:

https://kb.parallels.com/en/129699

I was able to create a docker image of SQL Server Express on my Mac. I have some questions:

1. What is my connection string, using the guide I provided?
2. Should I create a docker image inside of parallels or on Mac OS?
3. Can I download a docker image of SQL Server Management Studio?

I started the docker image on MacOS outside of parallels, but I cannot figure out the connection string. What is the server name? SQL? Is the user name also SQL?

I went into Azure data studio and I entered this connection string:

user sa
password VeryStr0ngP@ssw0rd
server localhost:1433

I also tried 3 IP address:

1. I googled what is my IP and I entered it.
2. In Parallels, I went to devices > network and I used that IP address.
3. I went into Mac OS > Network and clicked details, next to my WiFi.

When I connect without parallels, I get this error:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 35 - An internal exception was caught)
---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): nodename nor servname provided, or not known
at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(String hostName, Boolean justAddresses, AddressFamily addressFamily, Int64 startingTimestamp)

Comment: the superuser should be `sa` and you can connect with `localhost:1433`

Comment: Thanks. I tried, but it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

The host of your SQL server should be `localhost:1433` from your MacOS. And you can test, with a client in your MacOS, if you are able to connect to your SQL Server with this host.

But your parallel cannot use **localhost**. You need to look for the IP of your MacOS from your paralle and replace localhost with this IP. This documentation can help https://kb.parallels.com/4948

And be sure that the port `1433` is not blocked by a firewall